# Discrete Values Matrix: Select Rows and Scattered Plot problem

Tags: orange

I ran in a somewhat basic problem with Orange 3.3.1... but wonder if this is a bug or something I don't understand:

I have a Matrix, all with discrete values.
I select Columns, that goes ok
Select Rows... and use the « is one of » filter with 3 values out of 15 in a particular column.
But when I Scatter Plot. Values matching the filter seems to have been selected, but the X Axis still show X names, all of them,  that are not in « is one of ». On top of it, values have shifted to to wrong X name...

Anyone has an idea???

Regards

Comment: OK... If found my problem. I was also using the Paint Widget. Seems to introduce erroneous in the flow. I worked around it.

Comment: you should answer the question yourself, also putting the workaround into the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I removed the paint widget. Works fine witout it. That was in the version i had the problem. The latest daily build i installed after worked fine with the color widget. Thanks.